# How do two computers connect to same external address through NAT?

Tags: networking, routes, ip, nat

If I have two internal computers connecting to the same external IP address through a NAT router, how is the router able to get the traffic to the correct internal computer? It is my understanding that NAT forwards incoming packets to the computer that recently sent outgoing packets to the [incoming packet's] sender's IP address. Since both computers are sending to the same address, does the router forward the packet to both? If that is the case, is it the responsibility of the client software to determine which packets are relevant?

Is it possible if both computers are attempting to connect to the same port?

Comment: If you're asking if your IP-based program needs to be aware of NAT, the answer is no - that's why it's so successful.

Comment: There is an accepted answer, so I don't see the point in the bounty.

Comment: @RonMaupin he wants to offer some of his reputation bounty to an existing answer because he likes it or it helped him a lot. See the description of the bounty *One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty. Reward existing accepted answer*. People here do it quite often and reward extra bounty to good answers even after many years.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When you open a socket, you need to address a port of the destination system and open a conjugate listening port on your own system to receive any response. You have to send the destination system your listening port.

**Having more than one system using the same modem**

When you start a web browser, and go to www.google.com:80, your browser obtains/searches for a free non-system conjugate port from the system for listening. Let us say, the conjugate port is 10000. The  listener port is for receiving the http stream back from google.

Then your kid sitting next to you incidentally also browses www.google.com:80 and his/her google session of the play station or xbox-whatever also incidentally is assigned conjugate port 10000.

Both of you are sitting behind a cable modem, and behind the cable modem is your wireless router. And both of your systems are behind the wireless router - All sitting in that sequence, network topology-wise.

**To prevent port address collision on the router/modem**

Let us say that your cable company DHCP assigns your modem ip4 adress 72.72.72.72. But your wireless router DHCP assigns 192.168.0.10 to your system and to 192.168.0.11 to your kid's system.

When the frame carrying the information of your listener ports passes thro your NAT router, it would translate either one or both listening- ports. Let's say port 15000 for your page and port 16000 for your kid's page.

Your wireless router then sends your requests to google server as coming from 72.72.72.72:15000 and 72.72.72.72:16000.

The google server then responds individually to 72.72.72.72:15000 and 72.72.72.72:16000 and when you wireless router encounters the response, it reaches into the mapping that it has stored and translates 72.72.72.72:15000 to 192.168.0.10:10000 to reach your system but translates 72.72.72.72:16000 to 192.168.0.11:10000 to reach your kid's system.

**Running web/game/ftp/etc servers**

But what if you have a web server or an ftp server running on your system. What if you have two systems and both have a web server and both web servers are listening on port 80?

Let us say the local ip addresses registered/assigned with your wireless router of your first web server system is 192.168.0.30 and your second web server system is 192.168.0.40.

The wireless router would have a configuration web page usually by default 192.168.0.1:80, unless you changed it. There would be a tab to on the page where you could define/reserve application port mappings.

You could register with your wireless router to reserve the mapping

```
192.168.0.30:80 => outgoing port 8080
192.168.0.40:80 => outgoing port 8088
```

So that you have to phone your friends your web/game servers are addressable through
72.72.72.72:8080 and 72.72.72.72:8088 respectively,
where the wireless router would preclude its port 8080 and 8088 from its own dynamic NAT usage.

Of course, 72.72.72.72 is as good as only before your ISP DHCP decide to renew the ip4 address of your modem to say, 72.72.90.200. After which you would have to phone/email your friends and say
Hey, the servers' addresses have changed to 72.72.90.200:8080 and 72.72.90.200:8088 respectively. Or you could subscribe to dynamic dns (ddns) service to use a named domain where the ddns service will need you to install a simple heartbeat utility on your system to help them monitor the address variation. DDNS translation is a separate issue/strategy.

**NAT modems**

Newer ISP contracts supply you with a modem that has NAT. If so, you have to switch off either the one on your modem or the one on your wireless router. You should not use both - what's the point in translating twice because NAT is simply to prevent address collision. When you switch off NAT from your wireless router, it can operate as a hub switch and not a router anymore so that you could connect it to the modem using one of its LAN socket instead of thro its WAN socket.

Comment: +1 What an awesome explanation!  I have always been frustrated by the fact that most explanations of NAT never really cleared up how replies on outgoing connections make it back to the sender.

Comment: Does this mean, the number of connections per destination ip is limited to number of available port numbers. i.e. if an organization has more than 65k employees all try to access google.com (assuming ip is same) at the same time will not work if all of them are behind the same ip? What happens in this case? Is there a term for this?

Comment: Look at: https://www.freeccnastudyguide.com/study-guides/ccna/ch10/10-4-nat-overloading-aka-port-address-translation-pat/

Answer (score 4):

The router manages "source" ports that are separate for each computer.  While you may be connecting to port 80 on the "destination" the router may assign the source port to some high number port.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) sums it up as

> Network address translation involves
>   re-writing the source and/or
>   destination IP addresses and usually
>   also the TCP/UDP port numbers of IP
>   packets as they pass through the NAT.
>   Checksums (both IP and TCP/UDP) must
>   also be rewritten to take account of
>   the changes.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: Both computers initially request connection to 1.1.1.1 on port 1000. The router makes up new ports, 40000 and 40001. The router sends the packet along, still connecting on port 1000. When the server sends it back, it sends back to port 40000 or 40001. That makes sense, except that I thought when opening a connection, sending and receiving happen on the same port.

Comment: A "socket" consists of four pieces of data: origin IP address, origin port, destination IP, and destination port. In your example, ports 40000 and 40001 are source ports, 1000 is a destination port.

Answer (score 3):

Already good answers are provided, but here is another example:

```
    HOST A addr         HOST B addr
    10.1.0.2:4040       10.1.0.3:4040
-----------------------------------------
NAT 200.50.50.28:4040   200.50.50.28:4041 (what external host sees)
```

200.50.50.28 is router's global (internet) IP.

Every port number is unique in  the NAT table. And of course the router does all the *dirty* job of modifying the source and destination addresses transparently.

Comment: So if two computers uses the same source port the router automatically reassigns a new src port for any of the Host? And then the server that Host A and Host B connects to sees a different src port? If there is no collision on the ports of Host A and Host B the router wont change the src port? Just want to confirm if I understood it correctly. Thanks

Comment: @kuchi, yes the server sees a different port for each host. Routers in general resolve address collision, i.e. the same port can be used if two hosts connect to two different servers. The tuple `(src_ip, src_port, dest_ip, dest_port)` has to be distinct.

Answer (score 1):

It uses different ports for incoming external traffic, and the NAT then routes the packets on one port to one internal IP address, and the packets from the other port to the other internal IP address... The iniital request from each internal computer, when it goes through the NAT on the way out, establishes which port will be used for the incoming traffic from the external ip address, and it tells the external server what port to send it's traffic back on for that connection.

Answer (score 0):

Since public facing or external IP Address that was given by Internet Service Provider (ISP) has been discussed, I would like to add on this.
You can ask your ISP to have your public IP Address not change. It will become static, so that you do not have to inform your friends to change the IP Address if they want to access your server inside your Network Address Translator (NAT).
As of this writing, static IP Address cost around 100 bucks. Most of the ISP they call it business account.
You can determine your public facing IP Address by googling "what is my ip address".

Answer (score -1):

RFC3022 provides a lot of information on how this works