# Alternative to $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in php

Tags: php, ip-address

Is there any alternative to the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. Which returns the ip address of the computer accessing a site.
I'm trying to search about same external ip assigned by router, and got into this:
[How do two computers connect to same external address through NAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982222/how-do-two-computers-connect-to-same-external-address-through-nat)
And found out that the same external ip is assigned if the computers are connected to the same modem. 
I'm creating a simple login program in php which uses $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to determine if a user is already logged in somewhere else in the same network. And this won't actually work if those computers are connected to the same modem through the router.

Comment: Having IP address as the only user validation is a bad idea. You should set up sessions. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: @Diarmaid or HTTP Auth eg. http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: ip address is not sufficient for user authentication (e.g. what will you do if users are behind the same proxy ?), you should use session.

Comment: This is not a simple login program, this is a **bad** login program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a more traditional cookie based login solves this. The browser identifies the user by providing a unique token. Ip, as you have discovered, is not unique.

Comment: Thanks, just got an idea from what you said:}

Answer (score 7):

No, this is the best you can do. The server only knows where the request is coming from, and that *may* be a proxy or a NAT router or some other entity which is *not* the direct enduser. There's nothing you can do about that, that's how networks work.

The solution is simple: Don't use IPs to identify users. Ever. Use cookies.

Comment: I haven't said the whole story, I'm actually using sessions to store all the usernames who are logged in. And cookies to store the username and ip locally.